# RABL - combining collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabl

In my controller action I have two collections of events:

```
@recent = Event.recent
@popular = Event.popular
```

I would like to have JSON like follows:

```
{ "featured":[{},{}], "popular":[{},{},{}] }
```

Is it possible to achieve it in RABL template?  If so, what approach should i take?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Should `@recent` map to "featured" in the output JSON? The "popular" names match, just wondering about the other variable

Comment: Like this? https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/issues/319

Comment: @agronemann Yep, that technique did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: please check this https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/wiki/Tips-and-tricks